# SELECT INTO TABLE COUNT

Tags: sql, postgresql, function

```
EXECUTE format('Select Into taskgroup_cnt count(x.*)
        From %I.op_user_event_data a
        CROSS JOIN LATERAL
        json_array_elements((data->''taskGroups'')::json) As x
        Where a.event_id=' || cur_event_id, cur_instance);
```

In a function is throwing:

> ERROR:  syntax error at or near "count"
>
> LINE 1: Select Into taskgroup_cnt count(x.*)

What am I doing wrong here?

EDIT:

I managed to make it work, my problem was that I was having a dynamic query and wasn't able to write into the variables. This approuch solved the problem:

```
EXECUTE 'SELECT count(x.*) From '|| cur_instance ||'.op_user_event_data a 
        CROSS JOIN LATERAL
        json_array_elements((data->''taskGroups'')::json) As x
        WHERE a.event_id=' || cur_event_id
        INTO taskgroup_cnt;
```

All resumed to syntax.

Comment: Hint:  `select count(*) into taskgroup_cnt`.

Comment: That is giving me the opposite from what I want... thanks anyways!

Comment: If @GordonLinoff's hint gives you the opposite from what you want, then you probably misunderstood the syntax. In that case you should describe your desires so we know what you want.

Comment: Actually, not the opposite, I will edit my anwser based on @GordonLinoff 's anwser, which gave me a clue.

Comment: Actually make your solution as answer and set it as solution

Comment: will do. Thanks @davidbaumann ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
EXECUTE 'SELECT count(x.*) From '|| cur_instance ||'.op_user_event_data a 
        CROSS JOIN LATERAL
        json_array_elements((data->''taskGroups'')::json) As x
        WHERE a.event_id=' || cur_event_id
        INTO taskgroup_cnt;
```